# Fetch all results from table, list max of 6 results per row. If fewer than 6 results exists, list other items to fill space in row?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a total of 8 results/users in my MYSQL table 'users'.

I want to display 6 results/user profile images per row like so:

```
1st Result.   2nd Result.  3rd Result.  4th Result.   5th Result.  6th Result

7th Result.   8th Result.    No More Results.....
```

It is a requirement for each row to be complete with a minimum of 6 results/profile images. Where there is not enough results/profile images to complete a row, then I am trying to fill in the space with a template profile image 'advertise your profile here'.

The advertise here template image is stored in the following directory:

```
<div><img src="data/profile/0/main/advert.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></div>';
```

Giving the desired result:

```
1st Result.   2nd Result.  3rd Result.  4th Result.   5th Result.  6th Result

7th Result.   8th Result.    9 Ad Here.  10 Ad Here.  11 Ad Here.  12 Ad Here.
```

Here is my code I have currently with compliments to user @MegaColorBoy for helping me with the code so far.

However, the code is still not giving the desired result. Please can someone help improve amend the code to get it to give me the result i require. Thank you.

code:

```
 <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active' AND usertype = 'advertiser'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $limit = 6; 
        $chunks = array_chunk($result, $limit);

        foreach($chunks as $chunk){
        echo '<div id="category_case_holder">';
        foreach($chunk as $chunkItem){


        echo '<div id="prime"><a href="profile.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($chunkItem['user_id']).'"><img src="data/profile/'.htmlspecialchars($chunkItem['user_id']).'/main/profile.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></a></div>';


        }
        echo '</div>';

        } ?>
```

Comment: the above will only deal with 6 results rather than the full recordset because of `for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {`

Comment: can you explain `$filename = "data/profile/$i/main/profile.jpg";` - should that go from 0-5 for each row or 0 - N where N is length of recordset?

Comment: @RamRaider please see comment on your code and edited question. Essentially I am trying to display a complete sequence of at least 6 profile images per row. If there are not a minimum of 6 profiles per row - and lets say there are only 4 - then I am trying to fill the extra 2 spaces with 'advertise here' profiles. If that makes sense?

Comment: @Dharman it's the same question, but It's been edited for clarity

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

The following is wholly untested and perhaps wide of the mark having not seen the data nor had an answer regarding the profile image but the general aim was to break the results array into little bits - `array_chunk` is ideal for this.

```
<div id="category_case_holder">
    <?php

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status` = 'active' AND `usertype` = 'advertiser'";
        $result = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );

        # a placeholder in the path will be substituted later using sprintf or printf
        $filepath = 'data/profile/%s/main/profile.jpg';

        if( !empty( $result ) ){

            # split the recordset array into chunks - 6 records long. 
            # Each chunk will be a row from recordset.
            $chunks=array_chunk( $result, 6 );

            foreach( $chunks as $chunk ){
                echo '<div>';
                foreach( $chunk as $i => $rs ){

                    $filename=file_exists( sprintf( $filepath, $i ) ) ? sprintf( $filepath, $rs['user_id'] ) : sprintf( $filepath, '0' );
                    # ID attributes MUST be unique.
                    # substitue placeholders for values from this row data

                    printf('
                        <div class="prime">
                            <a href="profile.php?id=%s">
                                <img src="%s" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%">
                            </a>
                        </div>',
                        htmlspecialchars( $rs['user_id'] ),
                        $filename
                    );
                }
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }else{
            echo '<div id="prime"><img src="data/profile/0/main/advert.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></div>';
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this but i receive a too few arguments error on this line at $filename. Also please see updated question. Lets say for arguements sake, I only have 4 results in my table, i want a minimum of 6 divs showing in a row. Therefore, to fill in the missing 2 values, I replace these with 'advertising divs'. Otherwise if there are 6 or more values returned then I want 6 values per row. If that makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I think you should try this:

```
<div id="category_case_holder">
<table>
<tr>
<?php 
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active' AND usertype = 'advertiser'";
  $result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $resultNumber = count($result);
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $resultNumber; $i++) {
    echo "<td>";
    $key = $i - 1;
      if (isset($result[$key])) {
       $filename = "data/profile/$i/main/profile.jpg";
       if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo '<div id="prime"><a href="profile.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($result[$key]['user_id']).'"><img src="data/profile/'.htmlspecialchars($result[$key]['user_id']).'/main/profile.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></a></div>';
        } else {
          echo '<div id="prime"><a href="profile.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($result[$key]['user_id']).'"><img src="data/profile/0/main/profile.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></a></div>';
        }
      } else {
        echo '<div id="prime"><img src="data/profile/0/main/advert.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></div>';
      }
    echo "</td>";
    if (($i % 6) == 0 && $i <= $resultNumber) {
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
    }
  }
?>
</tr>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your code suggestion, however this isn't quite what I need. i have updated the question for clarity. Whilst i am trying to achieve 6 results per row, lets say for arguments sake that only 4 records exist in the database. Then i am trying to fill in the first row with the 2 missing results with advertising space.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve that using the `array_chunk()` method.

Example:

```php
//set it to whatever limit you want.
$limit = 6; 

// this will divide the array into x number of chunks based on y limit.
$chunks = array_chunk($result, limit);

foreach($chunks as $chunk){
   echo '<div>';
   foreach($chunk as $chunkItem){
      // your stuff here
   }
   echo '</div>';
}
```

Refer to PHP's official documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, however this fails to incorporate the rest of my code. For instance, in the event there aren't 6 results - lets say there are only 4. Then as a fail safe, i am trying to replenish the missing 2 results with 'advertise here' space. Can your code be amended to incorporate this?

Comment: Yes, just place a condition before the second loop: `if(count($chunk) < 6){//do something} else continue to loop`

Comment: please see updated question. If you could please offer some assistance i would be grateful.